# Store parts of a matrix in list object? in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, vectorization

I have a matrix which I like to split automatically in overlapping parts and store the result in a single list object. I like to have a solution without loops.

```
mat = matrix(c(1:24), 4)

list = NULL 
list[[1]] = mat[,c(1:2)]
list[[2]] = mat[,c(2:3)]
list[[3]] = mat[,c(3:4)]
list[[4]] = mat[,c(4:5)]
list[[5]] = mat[,c(5:6)]
```

**Expected output**

```
list
```

Thats what I like, but without to use a loop.

Comment: Look at `embed` to help with your column overlaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat)-1), function(i) mat[,c(i,i+1)])
```

Comment: by the way, why you use `seq_len` instead of `c(1:(ncol(mat)-1))`?

Comment: @and `seq_len(n)` and `c(1:n)` are the same.